# Pushing code to google source repos error

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos, google-source-repositories

I am getting the following error when pushing changes to my cloud source repo..

```sh
remote: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage]
remote: locale: "en-US"
remote: message: "Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier: https://source.developers.google.com/new-password"      
remote:
remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]
remote: request_id: "xxxxx"
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/p/xxx/repository/': The requested URL returned error: 400
```

I then go ahead to generate new password and store in *.gitcookies* file but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by generating a new .gitcookies identifier using the [Generate new identifier link](https://source.developers.google.com/new-password) and executing the command (sample is below) given after authentication with my account with the command line.

```sh
git config --global http.cookiefile "%USERPROFILE%\.gitcookies"
powershell -noprofile -nologo -command Write-Output ...
```

Initially because I saw powershell and all I used powershell and even git bash but they all did not work.

I found that for windows users, just copy the command for the windows users section and paste in windows command line and not powershell or git bash.

Comment: Where do you find the windows users section? I wanna see what's going on there too coz your answer doesn't make sense and it's not working for me.

Comment: After creating a repo on gcp source repos, you should be directed to the page that has info on how to clone your repo. Read the section with that info and you should see a section that shows info for windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think when working with multiple GCP account we encounters this problem even though we use the valid credentials.

Using VScode GUI faced the same problem. But when used the following traditional git CLI command it worked for me.

1. git add --all
2. git commit -m "commit message"
3. git push